# Oracle: TO_DATE can not parse result of TO_CHAR

Tags: oracle, to-date

I try to parse a time-string on a Oracle 12. Problem is the TZH I think.

```
SQL> select to_char(current_timestamp, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH') from dual;

TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIME
--------------------
05.07.2018 16:55 +02
```

But it is not working the other direction...

```
SQL> select TO_DATE('05.07.2018 16:53 +02', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH') from dual;
select TO_DATE('05.07.2018 16:53 +02', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH') from dual
                                       *
FEHLER in Zeile 1:
ORA-01821: Datumsformat nicht erkannt
```

It does not like the format. Also not working if I remove the +.

Comment: A `DATE` does not have a time zone and thus `to_date()` doesn't accept the TZH format mask. You need to use `to_timestamp()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, `TIMESTAMP` does not support time zones either. He must use `to_timestamp_tz()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, `TO_DATE` does not work with a time zone format mask.  Instead, use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ`, which does accept this:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('05.07.2018 16:53 +02:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI TZH:TZM')
FROM dual;
```

### Demo

It's not surprising that this is a source of confusion, because much of the documentation I saw online for `TO_DATE` mentions the `TZH` and `TZM` format masks, despite that they crash the function if used.